# Как полностью копировать свойство объекта в переменную внутри метода?

Tags: javascript

Если внутри метода объекта создать переменную и присвоить ей в качестве значения свойство этого же объекта, содержащее массив,

```
let cells = this.cells;
```

то при последующем удалении определенных значений из массива в переменной `cells` они удаляются также и из свойства `this.cells`. Как этого избежать? Как полностью **копировать** (клонировать) это свойство, а не просто создать ссылку на него?

Comment: Не уверен, но по аналогии с Питоном попробуйте `cells=array(this.cells)`

Comment: `Array.from` же.

Comment: @DNS сомневаюсь как минимум потому, что "array" - такого вообще нет.

Comment: @Other это в смысле что? Array вы имеете в виду именно Array? Класс? Или this.cells.from? Или это не метод вообще? Можно поподробнее? :)

Comment: Cорри, `new Array`, сморел [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: @DNS не покатит :) Везде, где можно использовать литерал, лучше использовать литерал. А здесь, я уверен, можно.

Comment: Тогда еще вариант - сложение с пустым массивом `cels = this.cells.concat('')` _Опять же использую аналогии, не большой проф в  JS_

Comment: @DNS это уже имеет право на жизнь. Но, согласитесь, решение товарища Other покрасивее будет. Но ваше решение мне тоже нравится

Comment: Ну я это и имел в виду... С синтаксисом не больно знаком, опыта маловато...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Массивы - ссылочные типы, поэтому их простым присваиванием не скопируешь.
Используйте [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (создаёт массив из массивоподобного объекта (массив - определённо массивоподобен :))):

```js
let obj = {arr: [1,2,3], _arr: [1,2,3]},
    a;
    
a = Array.from(obj.arr);
b = obj._arr;

console.info(a, obj.arr);
a.splice(1, 1);
console.info(a, obj.arr);

console.info(b, obj._arr);
b.splice(1, 1);
console.info(b, obj._arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Думаю, это то, что нужно. А какие еще типы данных являются "ссылочными"?

Comment: Типов в JS семь: "number", "string", "boolean", "null", "undefined", "symbol" и "object". Т. е. всё, что не строка, true/false, undefined или символ - объекты (технически, `null` - указатель на объект, но это считается примитивом).

Comment: Вроде как это баг. То, что null - объект. А про наличие Symbol вообще не знал

Comment: @smellyshovel, да, баг. Но из песни слов не выкинешь, так что живём с тем, что есть.

Answer (score 1):

Одним из стандартных способов клонирования объектов является их сериализация с последующей десериализацией.
Например, в JSON:

```js
var cells = [1, 2, {v: [3, 'Three']}, 4];

var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cells))

cells[2].v.splice(1, 1);

console.log(cells, copy);
```